# iOS - Code only works when I insert a breakpoint

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation

**Update**

I'm starting to figure this out. The AVAudioRecorder session gets activated and I get mic level readings for a few seconds. Then the async video code completes, the camera view displays, and I stop getting readings. It seems like the video is killing the audio session.

What's strange is that the code works on iOS 7 and won't work on iOS 6. Any ideas how to get around this. Is it a limitation on iOS 6?

I'm getting sound levels via the mic and I can only get them when I place a breakpoint on the code that sets up my audio recorder object. If I run without pausing at that point for a few seconds it can't get the levels. This code is in viewDidLoad and is and I can place the breakpoint on one of those first 3 lines:

```
_recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
[_recorder prepareToRecord];
_recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

    _levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.03 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

I get my levels in the levelTimerCallback method.

This code goes in viewDidAppear:

```
    NSError *error;

if (_recorder) {
    [_recorder record];
} else
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
```

Edit:

levelTimerCallback code:

```
    [_recorder updateMeters];

const double ALPHA = 0.05;
double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [_recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
_lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * _lowPassResults;

NSLog(@"Average input: %f Peak input: %f", [_recorder averagePowerForChannel:0], [_recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]);
```

Async code run above recorder code:

```
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [[[self captureManager] session] startRunning];
        });
```

Camera code:

```
    if ([self captureManager] == nil) {
    AVCamCaptureManager *manager = [[AVCamCaptureManager alloc] init];
    [self setCaptureManager:manager];

    [[self captureManager] setDelegate:self];

    if ([[self captureManager] setupSession]) {
        // Create video preview layer and add it to the UI
        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[[self captureManager] session]];
        UIView *view = [self videoPreviewView];
        CALayer *viewLayer = [view layer];
        [viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

        CGRect bounds = [view bounds];
        [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:bounds];

        if ([[newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer connection] isVideoOrientationSupported]) {
            [[newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer connection] setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
        }

        [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

        [viewLayer insertSublayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer below:[[viewLayer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0]];

        [self setCaptureVideoPreviewLayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer];

        // Start the session. This is done asychronously since -startRunning doesn't return until the session is running.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [[[self captureManager] session] startRunning];
        });


        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"captureManager.videoInput.device.focusMode" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:AVCamFocusModeObserverContext];

        // Add a single tap gesture to focus on the point tapped, then lock focus
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapToAutoFocus:)];
        [singleTap setDelegate:self];
        [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

        // Add a double tap gesture to reset the focus mode to continuous auto focus
        UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapToContinouslyAutoFocus:)];
        [doubleTap setDelegate:self];
        [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
        [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
        [view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    }
}

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setActive: YES error: nil];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error: nil];

NSError *error;
_recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
```

Comment: Obviously, it's likely that the breakpoint gives time for some async activity to complete before the above code starts mucking with things.  However, it's also the case that 0.03 seconds is an awfully short repeat interval for a timer, and it may simply be the case that the breakpoint allows the UI setup to proceed before the timer ties up the CPU.

Comment: What does "I can't get the levels" mean? `levelTimerCallback` is not called? What code do you have in `levelTimerCallback`? Adding some clarification will help you get a helpful answer here.

Comment: @HotLicks The short interval on the timer is because I'm checking mic levels to detect a spike.

Comment: @Cirrostratus I'm getting the db levels from the mic. If I don't use the breakpoint the levels are static (0). If I use the breakpoint the move up and down with the volume in the room. I'll add the code for that method.

Comment: @HotLicks I have a piece of async code which is run above the recorder code (I'll add it to the question). Could that be the problem?

Comment: But the recorder is detecting peaks for you.  You just need to update meters often enough to satisfy visuals -- about 10 per second should be plenty.

Comment: @HotLicks I changed it to 0.1 and then tried 1.0. No luck, it's still not working. Strangely it works perfectly fine on iOS 7. The problem is only on iOS 6.

Comment: (Can you really do an NSLog 30 times a second?)

Comment: @HotLicks It doesn't look that fast in my console but it's definitely moving pretty fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should call `_levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.03 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];`
 at the end of `viewDidAppear` instead, and nil it out and invalidate it in `viewDidDisappear`. Having a timer firing from `viewDidLoad` does not make sense when you have the other code in `viewDidAppear`. You may also want to check using the main thread instead of the background thread for `[[[self captureManager] session] startRunning];`.

Comment: Running [[[self captureManager] session] startRunning] in the main thread seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: This fixes the issue but creates a new one. The camera won't load unless I close and reopen the app.

Comment: I don't necessarily see camera code in your Q, only audio code. Is `captureManager` referring to some camera code?

Comment: Yes, I'm running a camera and listening for mic audio at the same time. I'm using a lot of Apples AVCam sample code. I'll include my entire viewDidLoad in the question above.