# AVFoundation -AVCaptureSession only stops and starts running when going to background and back with a breakpoint

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

This problem didn't occur in Xcode 10.2.1 and iOS 12. It started in Xcode 11.1 and iOS 13

My app records video, when the app goes to the background I stop the capture session from running and remove the preview layer. When the app comes back to the foreground I restart the capture session and add the preview layer back in:

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

// *** I initially didn't remove the preview layer in this example but I did remove it in the other 2 examples below ***
@objc fileprivate func stopCaptureSession() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        [weak self] in
        if self?.captureSession.isRunning == true {
            self?.captureSession.stopRunning()
        }
    }
}

@objc func restartCaptureSession() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        [weak self] in
        if self?.captureSession.isRunning == false {
            self?.captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is when I go to the background and come back the preview layer and ui is completely frozen. But before going to the background if i put a breakpoint on the line `if self?.captureSession.isRunning == true` and another breakpoint on the line `if self?.captureSession.isRunning == false`, once I trigger the breakpoints the preview layer and ui works fine.

Upon further research I came upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641706/ios-code-only-works-when-i-insert-a-breakpoint) and in the comments @HotLicks said:

```
Obviously, it's likely that the breakpoint gives time for some async activity to complete before the above code starts mucking with things. However, it's also the case that 0.03 seconds is an awfully short repeat interval for a timer, and it may simply be the case that the breakpoint allows the UI setup to proceed before the timer ties up the CPU.
```

I did a little more research and [Apple said](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/1388185-startrunning):

> The startRunning() method is a blocking call which can take some time,
>   therefore you should perform session setup on a serial queue so that
>   the main queue isn't blocked (which keeps the UI responsive). See
>   AVCam-iOS: Using AVFoundation to Capture Images and Movies for an
>   implementation example.

Using the comment from @HotLicks and the info from Apple I switched over to use `DispatchQueue.main.sync` and then `Dispatch Group` and after coming back from the background the preview layer and ui were still frozen. But once I add the breakpoints like I did in the first example and trigger them the preview layer and ui works fine.

**What am I doing wrong?**

**Update**

I switched from debug mode to release mode and it still didn't work.

I also tried switching to using `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async` and a timer `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5)` like @MohyG suggested but it made no difference.

Upon further inspection without the breakpoint the Background notification works fine but it's the Foreground Notification that's not getting called when the app enters the fg. For some reason the fg notification only triggers when I first put a break point inside the `stopCaptureSession()` function.

**The issue is the foreground notification only fires with the breakpoint I described above.**

I tried DispatchQueue.main.sync:

```
@objc fileprivate func stopCaptureSession() {

    if captureSession.isRunning { // adding a breakpoint here is the only thing that triggers the foreground notification when the the app comes back

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            [weak self] in

            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self?.captureSession.stopRunning()
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.previewLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
                self?.previewLayer = nil
            }
        }
    }
}

@objc func restartCaptureSession() {

    if !captureSession.isRunning {

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            [weak self] in
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self?.captureSession.startRunning()
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 15) {
                self?.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self!.captureSession)
                self?.previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                guard let previewLayer = self?.previewLayer else { return }
                previewLayer.frame = self!.containerViewForPreviewLayer.bounds
                self?.containerViewForPreviewLayer.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried Dispatch Group:

```
@objc fileprivate func stopCaptureSession() {

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    if captureSession.isRunning { // adding a breakpoint here is the only thing that triggers the foreground notification when the the app comes back

        group.enter()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            [weak self] in

            self?.captureSession.stopRunning()
            group.leave()

            group.notify(queue: .main) {
                self?.previewLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
                self?.previewLayer = nil
            }
        }
    }
}

@objc func restartCaptureSession() {

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    if !captureSession.isRunning {

        group.enter()

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            [weak self] in

            self?.captureSession.startRunning()
            group.leave()

            group.notify(queue: .main) {
                self?.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self!.captureSession)
                self?.previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                guard let previewLayer = self?.previewLayer else { return }
                previewLayer.frame = self!.containerViewForPreviewLayer.bounds
                self?.containerViewForPreviewLayer.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the rest of the code if needed:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appHasEnteredBackground),
                                           name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification,
                                           object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appWillEnterForeground),
                                           name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
                                           object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(sessionWasInterrupted),
                                           name: .AVCaptureSessionWasInterrupted,
                                           object: captureSession)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(sessionInterruptionEnded),
                                           name: .AVCaptureSessionInterruptionEnded,
                                           object: captureSession)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(sessionRuntimeError),
                                           name: .AVCaptureSessionRuntimeError,
                                           object: captureSession)

func stopMovieShowControls() {

    if movieFileOutput.isRecording {
        movieFileOutput.stopRecording()
    }

    recordButton.isHidden = false
    saveButton.isHidden = false
}

@objc fileprivate func appWillEnterForeground() {

    restartCaptureSession()
}

@objc fileprivate func appHasEnteredBackground() {

    stopMovieShowControls()

    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

    stopCaptureSession()
}

@objc func sessionRuntimeError(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let error = notification.userInfo?[AVCaptureSessionErrorKey] as? AVError else { return }

    stopMovieRecordigShowControls()

    if error.code == .mediaServicesWereReset {
        if !captureSession.isRunning {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {  [weak self] in
                self?.captureSession.startRunning()
            }
        } else {
            restartCaptureSession()
        }
    } else {
        restartCaptureSession()
    }
}

@objc func sessionWasInterrupted(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let userInfoValue = notification.userInfo?[AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReasonKey] as AnyObject?,
        let reasonIntegerValue = userInfoValue.integerValue,
        let reason = AVCaptureSession.InterruptionReason(rawValue: reasonIntegerValue) {

        switch reason {

        case .videoDeviceNotAvailableInBackground:

            stopMovieShowControls()

        case .audioDeviceInUseByAnotherClient, .videoDeviceInUseByAnotherClient:

            stopMovieShowControls()

        case .videoDeviceNotAvailableWithMultipleForegroundApps:

            print("2. The toggleButton was pressed")

        case .videoDeviceNotAvailableDueToSystemPressure:
            // no documentation
            break

        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
}

@objc func sessionInterruptionEnded(notification: NSNotification) {

    restartCaptureSession()

    stopMovieShowControls()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug and it was an extremely WEIRD bug.

The tint color of the images of the buttons are white. Instead of using a regular black background I wanted a blurred background so i used this:

```
func addBackgroundFrostToButton(_ backgroundBlur: UIVisualEffectView, vibrancy: UIVisualEffectView, button: UIButton, width: CGFloat?, height: CGFloat?){

    backgroundBlur.frame = button.bounds
    vibrancy.frame = button.bounds
    backgroundBlur.contentView.addSubview(vibrancy)
    button.insertSubview(backgroundBlur, at: 0)

    if let width = width {
        backgroundBlur.frame.size.width += width
    }

    if let height = height {
        backgroundBlur.frame.size.height += height
    }

    backgroundBlur.center = CGPoint(x: button.bounds.midX, y: button.bounds.midY)
}
```

And I called in `viewDidLayoutSubview()` like:

```
lazy var cancelButto: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    //....
    return button
}()

let cancelButtoBackgroundBlur: UIVisualEffectView = {
    let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))
    //...
    return blur
}()

let cancelButtoVibrancy: UIVisualEffectView = {
    let vibrancyEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(blurEffect: UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight))
    // ...
    return vibrancyView
}()

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

     // I did this with 4 buttons, this is just one of them
     addBackgroundFrostToButton(cancelButtoBackgroundBlur,
                               vibrancy: cancelButtoVibrancy,
                               button: cancelButto,
                               width: 10, height: 2.5)
}
```

Once I commented out the above code the `foreground notification` started firing with no problem and I didn't need the breakpoint anymore.

Since `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` can get called multiple times the `UIVisualEffectView` and the `UIVibrancyEffect` kept compounding on top of each other and for some **very WEIRD reason** it affected the `foreground notification`.

To get around it I simply created a `Bool` to check to see if the blurs were added to the button. Once I did that I had no more problems.

```
var wasBlurAdded = false

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

     if !wasBlurAdded {
         addBackgroundFrostToButton(cancelButtoBackgroundBlur,
                                   vibrancy: cancelButtoVibrancy,
                                   button: cancelButto,
                                   width: 10, height: 2.5)
         wasBlurAdded = true
     }
}
```

I don't know why or how this affected the `foreground notification observer` but like I said, this was an extremely WEIRD bug.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async` ?
Basically from what I got you need to cause a delay before `self?.captureSession.startRunning()` and `self?.captureSession.stopRunning()` .
A quick hacky solution to your question would be using manual delay like this:

`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {`

But its **NOT suggested**

You can try it to see if it fixes your problem though, If so you need to handle  the app transition states in `AppDelegate`

Basically when you are transitioning to background and foreground you need to manage somehow trigger your `captureSession`'s  start/stop in `AppDelegate` :

`func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {}`

and

`func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {}`

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion, about a hour ago I actually just tried both of your first suggestions. Right now I'm switching from debug mode to release mode to see what happens. I'll try your app delegate suggestion and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: I just added an 2 custom observers with the code above that listened for the bg and fg notifications. In app delegate I added 2 notifications in the delegates you listed that post to the vc. It didn't work. I even tried that with a combo of your first 2 suggestions, didn't work. Switching to release mode also didn't work. Thanks though :)

Comment: i found the answer. It's a weird bug. Your answer didn't repartee issues but I did wind up using your .background and the dispatchtimer because I saw a couple of other answers that used it too. I'm upvoting you because even though it didn't fix my problem, you was correct. Cheers!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating your own `DispatchQueue` and make it a serial queue (the default). This way you can be sure there isn't any concurrent access to the capture session. Do all your session access in the queue; you can use the `async` block on the queue so the thread you are calling it from won't block.